# Viewing multiple large images in the same ViewBox

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I am building a GUI using pyqtgraph to display a large image (~10GB), as well as an image mask that I would like to be able to toggle on/off quickly. Has anyone had success toggling between two large images in the same `ViewBox`?

My first idea was to add multiple `ImageItem` instances to the view, but only one seems to show up. I assume that this is because I am just displaying one image on top of the other, but I don't know how to send the front image to the back.

I also tried just initiating a single `ImageItem` and calling the `setImage()` method of `ImageItem`

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

# Interpret image data as row-major instead of col-major
pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with ImageView widget
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.resize(800,800)
imv = pg.ImageView()
win.setCentralWidget(imv)
win.show()
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ImageView')

image_item1 = pg.ImageItem( np.random.randint(255, size=(1000,1000)) )
image_item2 = pg.ImageItem( np.random.randint(255, size=(1000,1000)) )

imv.view.addItem(image_item1)
imv.view.addItem(image_item2)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

It makes sense to me that only one image would be shown using this method, but I am not sure how to make the other `ImageItem` appear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest adding a button to the gui and connecting its slot to the setImage method. 
Quick Example here: https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-signals-and-slots/